# Making labels not overlap with other features

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm trying to generate a label for distances in a Layout i'm making. For this I am using a line feature and making a label with it's distance (a calculated field) I know that the simple solution would be to just export it to CAD and using the DIM commmand, but it'd prefer to do it in a GIS to keep as much information as possible.

The measurement labels (shown with a yellow buffer) I have right now overlap with the actual polygons that compose the figure I'm trying to show:
[image]

I'm trying to find a way to make it so that the labels will only show, or will try to show not overlapping other features. Looking around the labels options I found an option that says something that would seem like a solution, the `Features act as obstacles` option, but when I enable It nothing changes:

[image]

If there's any way of accomplishing this the way it is right now (or getting the distance of sides of polygons in general in QGIS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @John](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/453096/making-labels-not-overlap-with-other-features#comment740393_453096):

> Go into your polygon layer label settings and in the drop down select
> blocking (instead of No labels and the other two options) and use the
> blocking options there.